# How to feed data to PagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I am using [this](http://geekyouup.blogspot.com/2011/07/viewpager-example-from-paug.html) example to use a `ViewPager` and a `PagerAdapter`.
But how could I feed the `PagerAdapter` with data from a adapter like `CursorAdapter` where I load the data using a `CursorLoader`?

The `.setAdapter()` on the `ViewPager` only takes a `PagerAdapter`. Then I would guess I need to bind the `CursorAdapter` within the `PagerAdapter`, but I could not find a way doing this.

Comment: hi, have you managed to solve your problem ? I also have similar scenario.

Answer (score 4):

Here's [a blog post](http://tumble.mlcastle.net/post/25875136857/bridging-cursorloaders-and-viewpagers-on-android) where I offer the source code for a `CursorPagerAdapter` which does what you appear to want.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `CursorAdapter`, just use the `Cursor` to populate the views in the `PagerAdapter`.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I use the `Cursor` from the `CursorLoader` to populate the view (within `instantiateItem`)?

Comment: Well there is two ways to go about it: 1. Try to duplicate what `CursorAdapter` does and get data when needed. That basically translates to calling `cursor.moveToPosition(pos)` when you need to get the `View` for position `pos` in your adapter. 2. Don't use a raw `Cursor` but  a list of your data (might be easier to implement, especially if don't have too many items). Load all of your data in a list, pass it to the `PageAdapter` and use it populate views as needed.